# How to sanitize the post_name value before inserting in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

How to sanitize the post_name value before inserting in WordPress?

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
$post_title = sanitize_title_with_dashes($post_title);
```

But WordPress does this for you already. I assume you need it for something different?

Comment: @Anraiki: But it doesn't do it with *dashes*. ;-)

Seriously though, `sanitize_title()` leaves spaces which you don't want in `post_name`.

Comment: That's odd. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title Unless, I am reading it wrong with the example they are showing there. 'This Long Title is what My Post or Page might be' -> 'this-long-title-is-what-my-post-or-page-might-be'

Comment: @Anaraiki - My bad. I read the code `sanitize_title()` and assumed that the filter called in the code was to allow plugins to filter but instead core actually uses it. `sanitize_title()` first calls `strip_tags()` and then invokes a filter which ultimately calls `sanitize_title_with_dashes()`. So unless there's a concern that HTML will creep in then `sanitize_title_with_dashes()` is a tiny bit more performant and probably the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Some solution might be found at http://postedpost.com/2008/06/23/ultimate-wordpress-post-name-url-sanitize-solution/

Also, you might want to do it as follows:

```
$special_chars = array("?", "[", "]", "/", "\\", "=", "<", ">", ":", ";", ",", "'", "\"", "&", "$", "#", "*", "(", ")", "|", "~", "`", "!", "{", "}");
$post_name = str_replace(' ', '-', str_replace($special_chars, '', strtolower($post_name)));
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. The next answer (using sanitize_title_with_dashes) is right. We are not re-inventing the wheel, we are using an existing API>

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're sanitizing by direct SQL insertion. Instead, consider using wp_post_insert() in your insertion script.

```
$new_post_id = wp_insert_post(array(
  'post_title' => "This <open_tag insane title thing<b>LOL!;drop table `bobby`;"
));
```

At this point, you just worry about your title - and not the slug, post name, etc.  WP will take care of the rest and (at least security) sanitization.  The slug, as demonstrated in the screenshot, becomes fairly usable.

[image]

This function can be used by simply doing `include( "wp-config.php" );` and going about your business without any other PHP overhead.

If you are dealing with some funky titles to begin with, a simple strip_tags(trim()) might do the trick. Otherwise, you've got other problems to deal with ;-)